# fprintf - Print a specific numbers of characters per line

Tags: c

For example I have some x,y coordinate.
How can I print multiple x,y on the screen so that I have only 4 of these coordinates per line.

So let us say that all x and y are the same throughout and I want this printed out where x = 1 and y = 2.

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
..............
```

Fprintf(?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want exactly four per line, just do this:

```
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", x, y, x, y, x, y, x, y);
```

for as many lines as you want.

Comment: While this is the easiest form, I am interested in the solution where the numbers are arbitrarily chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have something like this:

```
typedef struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} point_t ;

#define NUM_OF_LINES 5
#define POINTS_PER_LINE 4

int main( void ) {
    point_t p[NUM_OF_LINES][POINTS_PER_LINE];

    //  fill points with valid data somehow

    // print points
    for (int i = 0; i != NUM_OF_LINES; i++) {
        for( int j = 0; j != POINTS_PER_LINE; j++ )
            printf("%d %d ", p[i][j].x, p[i][j].y);

        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd print that space before the numbers and only if j!=0. While it seems largely unimportant, it can be somewhat a pain if the rest of your line occupy exactly one line in the viewport, and it wraps long lines, so you end up with extra lines containing single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<total_points; i++) {
    printf("%d %d", points[i].x, points[i].y);
    if (i % points_per_line == 0)
        printf("\n");
    else
        printf(" ");
}
```

...or, if you don't mind code that some might consider slightly "tricky":

```
static char seps[] = {'\n', ' '};

for (int i=0; i<total_points; i++)
    printf("%d %d%c", 
        points[i].x,
        points[i].y,
        seps[(i%points_per_line)==0]);
```

Either way, these obviously presume something like the normal definition of a point, something on the order of:

```
typedef struct { 
    int x;
    int y;
} point;
```

Comment: Uhg, at least make that `static char` into `static const char`... Better would be `'\n'+(' '-'\n')*!(i%points_per_line)` or simply use `?:`...

Comment: @R. Making the array `const` is (IMO) harmless but mostly pointless. Do you *honestly* think: `'\n'+(' '-'\n')*!(i%points_per_line)` is *better*? That strikes me as justification for corporal punishment.

Comment: A non-const `static` array (used where `const` would do fine) will enlarge the program's non-sharable data segment for no good reason. Your example is small, but I've seen examples of hundreds of KB or even some MB wasted by this kind of mistake. That's why I pointed it out. Anyway both the array and my replacement are ugly; I guess it's a matter of taste which one is worse.

Comment: @R. Even for the minuscule number of multitasking OSes that don't use COW, we're talking about 2 bytes here. Even back in the CP/M days that was rarely enough to get very excited over. I suppose it *is* a matter of taste, but it seems to me you've asked to replace my hamburger with a pound of cow manure. Hamburger may not be gourmet cooking, and may not fit your particular taste -- but it's still hard to imagine anybody preferring to eat feces.

Comment: Ok here is the nice version: `(i%points_per_line)?' ':'\n'`. Better?

Comment: @R.: I don't like it as well personally, but at least I can see where somebody else could.

Comment: OK. And again I wasn't worried about two bytes. I was disapproving of advice that misuses `static` where `static const` would be appropriate. Note that use of plain `static` also creates a smell - grepping for `static` without `const`, or more likely using `size(1)` to find files with non-empty data/bss, will give a false positive for possible global state (which should be considered a major potential bug).